# Cleaning up resources on program exit / crash

Tags: java

I have a class whose instances use some resources (sockets, files) during their lifetime. The class provides a `disconnect()` method that should be called after finishing work. But since programs tend to crash, especially during development, i want to make sure that the close method is called, no matter what happened.

Is there a way to do that?

I read about `finalize()`, but it only seems to run, if the object is garbage collected. I also read about try-with-resources, but i would have to refactor a big part of my library code to integrate that.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)

Comment: Most resources are cleaned up by the OS when a process terminates (sockets, file handles, ...). Things you would have to deal with are for example lock files.

Comment: @Henry files are unlocked too. All OS resources are released.

Comment: @talex with a lock file I meant a file created to lock out other processes from accessing a resource. The lock file is removed by the owning process once the resource is free again. When the owning process dies unexpectedly the lock file would remain.